# bash/shell - How do I get the group name of a directory on RHEL and save it to a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, permissions, rhel

I'm working on a script to create users and grant them access to a directory, but they have to be added to the group that has permissions on the directory.  I noticed that if I do a stat on the directory I can list out the group name:

```
[root@pizzaServer myuser]# stat /ftp/PizzaFolder
  File: ‘/ftp/PizzaFolder’
  Size: 22              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 2108605     Links: 3
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   **Gid: (1934800276/PizzaGroup)**
```

And then I can grep it:

```
[root@pizzaServer myuser]# stat /ftp/PizzaFolder | grep Gid
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (1934800276/PizzaGroup)
```

And then possibly use sed to crop out the group name?  Is that the best method or is there another way?  I only want the group name "PizzaGroup" as an output.

Comment: Have you read `man 1 stat`? It might prove useful.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Use the `-o` option to `stat` to specify which information you want returned. Then you don't need to parse anyting.

Comment: I only want the group name "PizzaGroup" so I can save it to a variable.  I reviewed the man pages for stat but I didn't understand how to use the %G option? Not sure

Comment: `stat -c %G <filename>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get group name of owner:

```
stat -c "%G" /ftp/PizzaFolder
```

See: `man 1 stat`